# How to fix json to model conerversion?

Tags: json, flutter, flutter-web, dio

I am calling api using [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio). My API url is [this](https://raviganwal.github.io/project.json)

```
class NetworkRepository {
  Future<String> getRequest(String url) async {
    var dio = Dio();
    Response response = await dio.get(url);
    return json.encode(response.data);
  }
  dynamic requestInterceptor(RequestOptions options) async {
    return options;
  }
}
```

I am calling `getRequest(String url)` in my widget,

```
  Future<String> getProjects() async {
    await NetworkRepository().getRequest(projects).then((onValue) {
      var dataConvertedToJSON = json.decode(onValue);
        AndroidProjectModel model = AndroidProjectModel.fromJson(dataConvertedToJSON);
        print(model.toString()); //DOES NOT PRINT ANYTHING
    });
    return 'success';
  }
```

I pass `dataConvertedToJSON` into `AndroidProjectModel.fromJson(dataConvertedToJSON)` and it does not retrun anything.
I am converting JSON to model using [this tool](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/).

Answer (score 0):

`await` and `then` clauses might not work together. Try something like the following.

```dart
var jsonResponse = await NetworkRepository().getRequest(projects);
var dataConvertedToJSON = json.decode(onValue);
AndroidProjectModel model = AndroidProjectModel.fromJson(dataConvertedToJSON);
print(model.toString());
```

**OR**

Remove the `await` and use only the `then` handler.

Comment: Thank you for comment, but I tried that too did not work either.

Comment: although I changed my JSON a bit and somehow it is working!

Answer (score 0):

Use **try..catch**, might be works

```
try {
      final response = await Dio().get(url);
      dynamic jsonResponse = response.data;
      print("response body :: $jsonResponse");
}
on DioError catch(error) {
      print('Error Details :: ${error.message}');
      dynamic jsonResponse = error.response.data ?? " ";
      print("response body :: $jsonResponse");
}
```

Comment: Thank for your efforts. It was my bad and I have already solved it as I mentioned in a comment of 1st answer.

Comment: Glad to hear that and I did not notice that you already solved, but I found i already done in my project so posted answer.